# Non-persistent entities v.s. manual POJO + View + Controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

I've successfully created a basic Spring Web MVC application using Roo, which I might add, was a treat! The application uses persistence (HIBERNATE + HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY), which is what you'd want for many POJOs.

Now, suppose I'd like to write some custom method which is to be accessed from the View-side, like end-of-day calculations or what have you. My immediate thoughts about how to implement these are either

1) Create an entity, keep it from using persistence and implement the desired method(s) for this class, rely upon MVC-scaffolding for presentation

or

2) Create the POJO + View + Controller manually

What is my best alternative? Is 1) even possible (i.e. not using persistence for entities through roo)? And if so: is it so that the .java files may be freely edited, while the .aj files are handled by Roo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is absolutely Ok using Roo's `entity` command. You can create new entity in Roo shell and then perform scaffolding without any problem. And then you can edit your *.java part without problems too. The only recommendation is to keep Roo shell running while editing.

Comment: thank you very much! Just out of curiosity: what would you say is the best way to suppress persistence? Simply remove CRUD-capabilities from the View and keep Controller and Model as it is?

Comment: If I understand you right you can manage Controller's persistance related methods using Controller's `@RooWebScaffold` annotation (see [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/org.springframework.roo.annotations/apidocs/org/springframework/roo/addon/web/mvc/controller/RooWebScaffold.html)). Just set `create`. `delete`, `update` to `false` with Roo console running.

Comment: Thanks again - that is so cool! Just what I needed. BTW: a quick search suggests that the "controller scaffold" command using "--disallowedOperations create,update,delete" will do the trick as well.